# Convector env:restart throws cryptogen: cannot execute binary file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, convector

Running `npm run env:restart` results in the following error:

```
...
[hurley] - Running cryptoconfigsh
/bin/bash: line 25: /Users/ecairol/hyperledger-fabric-network/fabric-binaries/1.3.0/bin/cryptogen: cannot execute binary file
[hurley] - Found error while running script!
```

I have tried installing from scratch two projects with the same result.
Node version: v8.12.0

Answer (score 1):

> waltermontes Today at 10:46 PM
>
> Looks like the binary files are not compatible for your OS version,
>   that usually happens when you run hurley inside of a Docker or
>   something like that.
>
> Remove the folder
>   `/Users/username/hyperledger-fabric-network` and try again, everything
>   should be downloaded again fine